# undefined is not an object(ecaluating 'ReactInternals.ReactCurrentOwner')

Tags: react-native, npm

I want to run my react-native project, but an error occurred.
Please give me advise.

Environment

```
$ npm list --depth=0
nav@0.0.1 /Dev/lrn/rn/nav
├── babel-jest@20.0.3
├── babel-preset-react-native@1.9.2
├── jest@20.0.4
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0-alpha.6
├── react-native@0.45.1
├── react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.11
└── react-test-renderer@16.0.0-alpha.12
```

Project Directory

```
$ls
__tests__         index.android.js  node_modules      yarn.lock
android           index.ios.js      package-lock.json
app.json          ios               package.json
```

What I Do

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install
$ react-native run-ios
```

Error
[Red Screen iPhone Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBv5y.png)

I think environment was wrong, but what I do cannot correct it.
Thank you for seeing and any advice is welcome. thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem, after doing some reading on their [Github Issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13874)

```
yarn add react@16.0.0-alpha.12
```

or

```
npm i react@16.0.0-alpha.12 --save
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: where to add this yarn add react@16.0.0-alpha.12 ??

Comment: @Rajasekherreddy Run it from your terminal. Yarn is another package manager, similar to npm, that also uses the package.json in addition to its own yarn.lock lockfile

Comment: What if I don't use yarn?

Comment: you should consider switching. but the equivalent command for npm would be `npm install react@16.0.0-alpha.12`